# MS Access VBA Compile Error on "x="

Tags: ms-access

Everytime I try to compile my VBA code, I'm getting an error that says "Can't find project or library".

I have no idea which library I'm missing because all that the debugger highlights is a portion of one of my VBA lines:

```
x=
```

the full line looks like this:

```
x = MsgBox("You must select a manufacturer")
```

Any clues what library I need to include?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Hans,

I didn't notice that one of my references was labeled as "MISSING".
...

First thing to check: from VB Editor main menu, choose Tools->References. If any of the selected (checked) references are "Missing", all sorts of weird crap can happen with your code. Fix any that are missing